# MySQL locking problem

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I have a simple setup of a set of writers and a set of readers working with a MySQL ISAM table. The writers are only inserting rows while the readers are only checking for new rows.

OK, so I know that I don't need a lock in this situation, since I'm not modifying existing rows. However my Writers are accessing one more table that *does* need a lock. I piece of information seems irrelevant except for the following limitation stated in the MySQL documentation:

> A session that requires locks must
>   acquire all the locks that it needs in
>   a single LOCK TABLES statement. While
>   the locks thus obtained are held, the
>   session can access only the locked
>   tables. For example, in the following
>   sequence of statements, an error
>   occurs for the attempt to access t2
>   because it was not locked in the LOCK
>   TABLES statement:

So to access the table I want to insert rows into, I NEED to lock it, which is causing me performance problems. Any suggestions of how to get around this?

Comment: You should give us more info about the pertinent table and exactly why you need it locked. This will give us a better idea of what alternatives may be available to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you lock and unlock immediately around the queries which need locking.  The documentation is simply stating that for any set of queries run while you have a lock, all tables involved must be locked.  You can unlock as soon as you're done and touch any other tables.

Also consider that InnoDB supports row-level locking, which is often preferable to table-locking for performance since other queries on other rows will not be locked out for reading while you're also writing.